# How to get JSONArray data with retrofit2.0?

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface newArtsApi {

    @GET("art/get_all_arts?page=1")
    Call<List<ArtsPagination>> getMovies(@Query("index") int index);}
```

Another ServiceGenerator class looks like this:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

        OkHttpClient httpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        gson.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringDesirializer());

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://...../clients/....../api/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);

    }
}
```

I want this type of data using Retrofit 2.0, jsonarry_data

[image: JSONARRAY_DATA]

but I get error for parsing this type of data.

Comment: Getting error like this.. from above code...Response Error for Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Basically the error is saying that your JSON is returning an object, in your API you've specified that it should receive a List of ArtsPagination, in the JSONARRAY_DATA image that you posted it's returning one single object.

Comment: so can u explain in detail that how can i get it... where i make changes..?

Comment: Check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

```
    Call<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            // Log.w("ResponseCode ",response.body().getResults()+"");
            List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the list of ArtsPagination, your code is ok the problem is on the server side because it's response isn't coming in a list. If you want to receive only one object you need to change this on your interface:

```
Call<ArtsPagination> getMovies(@Query("index") int index);
```

Changing this and you'll  also need to update your `onResponse` and `onFailure` methods to handle the response as one single object.